# How to copy data from one database/table to another Remote one by it's Ip

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to copy data from one database/table to another Remote one by it's IP
this my code

```
INSERT INTO dtin select * From [66.22.100.70].MainData.dbo.dtin where dtin_code='ttr'
```

Comment: go through linked Servers

Comment: @lad2025 you are machine

Comment: @lad2025 but it make huge...your brain never sleeps ....hahaha

Comment: sorry but i cant get what you mean i'am already get the connection string for the remote sql server and connect it by it's Ip Using the Internet and also the local data base connection is ok now i want to insert atable from the remote one to local one in my search  i get this code INSERT
INTO    localTABLE
SELECT  *
FROM    [LINKEDSERVER\INSTANCE].remoteDATABASE.remoteSCHEMA.remoteTABLE    but the problem i am use the ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily accomplished using the `SqlBulkCopy` class:

```
Private Const SOURCE_CONNECTIONSTRING As String = "..."
Private Const TARGET_CONNECTIONSTRING As String = "..."


Using table As DataTable = New DataTable
    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(SOURCE_CONNECTIONSTRING)
        connection.Open
        Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", connection)
            Using adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source)
                adapter.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Using copier As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(TARGET_CONNECTIONSTRING, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls)
        For Each column As DataColumn In table.Columns
            If Not GetType(SqlGeography) Is column.DataType Then    
            '   Azure doesnt like geography      '
                copier.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName)
            End If
        Next

        copier.DestinationTableName = "tableName"
        copier.BulkCopyTimeout = 0

        copier.WriteToServer(table)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks about your Answer But there is no way to use like this code                INSERT INTO localTABLE SELECT * FROM [LINKEDSERVER\INSTANCE].remoteDATABASE.remoteSCHEMA.remoteTABLE                                                                                                             but by th IP of The Remote SQL Server??

Comment: @EbnEleslaam: Not that I am aware of.  Its been so long ago since I last used a linked server, but I believe you can name a linked server.  If you were to name the server with the ip address you might be able to "fool" the system that way.  That would only work if the target server has a static ip.   The bulk copier method is much easier since you can construct your target connection string using the appropriate ip address.

Comment: Thanks but what is the need of  If Not GetType(SqlGeography) Is column.DataType Then   Because it is get error with me

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but u need to do some plumbing work first.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='192.168.0.200'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '192.168.0.200', 'false', NULL, 'sa', 'administrator'
```

then

```
insert into [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale ([Url]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Subtitle]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Price]
      ,[LivingArea]
      ,[RoomCount]
      ,[PostCode]
      ,[TotalArea]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateRemoved]
      ,[DateLastProcessed]
      ,[ServiceCosts]
      ,[HeatingType]
      ,[IsBendrabutis]) 

select [Url]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Subtitle]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Price]
      ,[LivingArea]
      ,[RoomCount]
      ,[PostCode]
      ,[TotalArea]
      ,[DateAdded]
      ,[DateRemoved]
      ,[DateLastProcessed]
      ,[ServiceCosts]
      ,[HeatingType]
      ,[IsBendrabutis] from WebAnalyzer.dbo.Sale where url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in
( 
select url COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT From [192.168.0.200].webanalyzer.dbo.sale
)
```